# Not able to view calendar in my profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, visited-days

Previously when I used to click on a link in front of the visited field in my profile, it was showing me a calendar showing me how many days I have logged in consecutively.

Today I tried it many times, but it is just loading and not showing anything.

What happened to it?

Comment: It does say it's loading, there's a loading image at the right. It just never loads.

Comment: Javascript error in Chrome `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'datepicker'`

Comment: Works fine in Win7 + FF 3.6.15.

Comment: Safari 5 says "TypeError: Result of expression `'$('#calendar').datepicker' [undefined]` is not a function."

Comment: They have now corrected it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, my bad - the calendar is the only place that uses jquery ui; I had moved the script reference and tested locally, but "works on my machine.. as a dev" doesn't always cut it :P